# Something wrong with nscalendar

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar

I can't understand what happening here :( :

```
NSLog(@"date : %@, hours : %d", self.now, [[self.calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:self.now] hour]);
```

result

```
date : 2000-01-01 01:00:19 +0000, hours : 2
```

Why is it not hours : 1 ? An idea ?

EDIT:

```
self.calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
```

and self.now is just a date.

Comment: Could you provide code where you initialize `calendar` and `now` objects?

Comment: `NSLog(@"date : %@", date)` prints the date in GMT. `[calendar components:...]` uses your current time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple docs:

> Returns the number of hour units for the receiver.
>
> ```
> - (NSInteger)hour
> ```
>
> Return Value: The number of hour units for the receiver.
>
> Discussion: This value is **interpreted in the context of the calendar**
>   with which it is used

Calendar context makes `hour` component depending on time zone that set to `calendar` object.
When you init `calendar` by calling
`[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];`
it automatically retrieve time zone from device settings.

In log we see GMT+0 time zone (`2000-01-01 01:00:19 +0000`). I guess your time zone is GMT+1. In this case NSCalendar works correctly.

Comment: Thanks ! I thought NSCalendar wasn't depending of the time zone